# Selecting a test to prove that the observed changes in the performance of two machine learning models are statistically significant

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

I have developed two machine learning models which I evaluated with two different datasets. My initial hypothesis was that their performance would be higher in dataset 2 as compared to dataset 1. After calculating the metrics (Accuracy, MCC, Balanced Accuracy, Sensitivity, Specificity, PPV, NPV, and a few others) I noticed that indeed their performance seemed better in dataset 2.
However, to sure that this difference I'm seeing is real and not by chance I thought to do a statistical analysis. My first reaction was to perform a Fisher's exact test but after reading more about this test, I believe it might not be the right choice for what I am trying to prove. What other tests can you suggest in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I will give a possible reference: Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688.